Spring Database Initialization missing first INSERT statement
I have a simple Spring app, which when I start I want to have my data in it. I wanted to try https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/how-to/data-initialization.html
This is my application.yaml file
spring:
  application:
    name: supermarket

  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/supermarket?useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: root
    password: root

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    defer-datasource-initialization: true

  sql:
    init:
      data-locations: classpath:data.sql
      mode: always

This is my data.sql, which is in my resources folder.
INSERT INTO supermarket.categories(`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'Category-1');
INSERT INTO supermarket.categories(`id`, `name`) VALUES (2, 'Category-2');
INSERT INTO supermarket.categories(`id`, `name`) VALUES (3, 'Category-3');
INSERT INTO supermarket.categories(`id`, `name`) VALUES (4, 'Category-4');
INSERT INTO supermarket.categories(`id`, `name`) VALUES (5, 'Category-5');

When I start my app and check the DB I am missing the first entry. The stange thing is that when I duplicate the first entry:
INSERT INTO supermarket.categories(`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'Category-1');
INSERT INTO supermarket.categories(`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'Category-1');
INSERT INTO supermarket.categories(`id`, `name`) VALUES (2, 'Category-2');
INSERT INTO supermarket.categories(`id`, `name`) VALUES (3, 'Category-3');
INSERT INTO supermarket.categories(`id`, `name`) VALUES (4, 'Category-4');
INSERT INTO supermarket.categories(`id`, `name`) VALUES (5, 'Category-5');

then I see it inserted.
Has anyone faced an issue like this before?
